# Xcode8 : Why Xcode8 is not building/compiling after converting to Swift3 syntax's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I just ran my project in Xcode8 it asked me to convert to swift3 syntax's so I did it, Obviously there are many errors those errors I am fixing from 2 days. After I converted all to swift3 step by step(error resolving). But when I build it is not even ran once either in device or simulator.

Why it is not moving further ?

It is not even throwing any errors to fix any(checked all again and again)

I am worried. Is there anything I need to check in build settings or in code ?

Please refer below image

[image]

Warnings:

[image]

Comment: How long has this been going on? It happened to me as well the first time after it actually managed to make a build i.e. after fixing the errors from the conversion

Comment: from 2 days it is like that only i don't know what was wrong !!! wether it is Xcode8 bug or some build settings or code prob ........

Comment: Any solution @tech4242

Comment: So if you were to build it now again, it would stop there and you could basically leave it for hours and it doesn't move one bit?

Comment: yes exactly it doesn't moving a bit from there @tech4242

Comment: Can you list your build warnings? There seem to be 10 of them, which are not visible in your screenshot. Maybe there is a framework or something else that doesn't want to compile

Comment: Added warnings image  @tech4242

Comment: My guess is that there is some piece of code that the compiler is struggling to resolve type inference for. Try a binary search in commenting out bits of your code to see if it compiles faster. Also you might want to try deleting derived data for your and for XCode in general.

Comment: I removed all the Derived Data no use. How can i trace that piece of code? @Nailer

Comment: Thanks for editing @Umair Afzal

Comment: Usually it is deeply nested type inference scenarios, but I think the Swift compiler has had trouble with random stuff before. Specifically compiling literal array declarations. It's hard to tell for me, since I haven't started using Swift 3 just yet. I'm just basing my assumption on previous problems with the Swift compiler.

Comment: I got it  thank you for your comments which helped me to think about the issue. so i posted answer for others(if any face issue the same). Thank you again for all

Answer (score 1):

#### Xcode8 Compiler Bug :

Sometimes Compiler is not detecting all errors in Xcode8

So I started commenting one by one method/class in swift files

There i found one method is troubling compiler which has not updated to swift3 syntax's after that i changed those syntax's then it ran successfully

Many things we need to check if anyone facing above issue in Xcode8 Swift3 Please refer below syntax's

Thank you for the above comments which helps me to think about the issue

#### NSFetchRequest Before :

```
 //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
```

#### NSFetchRequest in Swift3:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Sample>(entityName: "Sample")
```

---

#### Note: **All delegate methods please re - write

---

#### Declaring a method with parameters - no change but in calling this method

```
func getPageThumbnail(upc:String, pagenum:Int)-> UIImage
 {

 }
```

Before:

```
if let xImage = GF.getPageThumbnail(self.upcLabel.text!, pagenum: 3) as UIImage?
```

Now in Swift3:

```
if let xImage = GF.getPageThumbnail(upc:self.upcLabel.text!, pagenum: 3) as UIImage?
```

#### Dispatch Queues in Swift3 :

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {


        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        }

}
```

#### Swift3: CGRectMake to CGRect

```
CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:80, height:80)
```

#### CGPointMake to CGPoint

```
CGPoint(x:10,  y:20);
```

#### Selectors in Swift3:

```
let myTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped(_:)) )

func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
}
```

#### Subscript in Swift3

```
extension String {


//   right(x) and left(x) function to get substring
func right(i: Int) -> String?
{
    return self[self.length-i ... self.length-1 ]
}


func left(i: Int) -> String?
{
    return self[0 ... i-1]
}



subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
    return self[self.characters.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return String(self[i] as Character)
}

//added  swift3 replacement
subscript (r: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
    get {
        let startIndex =  self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
        return self[startIndex...endIndex]
    }
}
}
```